# Data gets corrupted when transferring bytes from C++ to Java

Tags: java, c++, sockets, boost-asio

My C++ server uses the following code to send to my Java client the number 11

```
boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
tcp::socket* server_socket;
...
size_t check = boost::asio::write(*server_socket, boost::asio::buffer("11", 2), ignored_error);
```

check is equal to 2, so there's no problem on the server side.

My Java client receives the data using the following code

```
Socket tcpSocket;
BufferedInputStream inFromServer;
...
String temp = "";
for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    temp += (char) inFromServer.read();
int num_of_filters = Integer.parseInt(temp); //Here the following error is thrown

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: could it be related to different endianess maybe ?

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi I doubt it. its sent as raw chars. But it *might* be a Unicode problem, of which java strings are, and the incoming buffer is *not*.

Comment: The first thing you're doing wrong is that you aren't checking for end of stream anywhere. If you're expecting exactly two bytes I would use DataInputStream.readFully().

Comment: @EJP End of stream is not the problem here. Tried to use DataInputStream.readFully(), but same error was thrown.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but I would start with investigating the encoding on both ends. 
then recieve the bytes and use `new String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)`

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better off using one of the common libraries to read it instead of going through byte-by-byte yourself.  For instance, using apache commons IO you could just:

```
    String temp = IOUtils.toString(inFromServer);
```